# Ubuntu does not detect USB stick with lsblk or fdisk

Tags: usb, mount, 17.04, fat32, detect

I have a usb stick that needed formatting because ubuntu couldn't detect it or mount it. I found a few solutions online and used lsblk and fdisk commands to list out all devices that are attached. I could see it and when I tried to format it or use mkfs command to make it fat32, I got an error and eventually made things worse, cause now I can't see usb using lsblk or fdisk.
I can see it's plugged in using lsusb as unknown, but don't know what to do from there and how to get it back in life.
Gparted and Disk utility doesn't see it also, but with other usb stick's everything is ok, so it's not the Ubuntu drivers.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Sounds like a bad USB stick.

Comment: yeah, it probbably is, but can it be fixed and how?
a college friend told me that he can fix it, has the tools to do it, but we're on vacation and he in another city.
that's why I tried to use Gparted, Disk and Terminal commands, but no luck :/

Comment: There may be some special software tools that can try, but I'm not aware of them. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Install gparted
    sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install gparted

[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpGeB.jpg)

Comment: Last sentance in my post said "Gparted and Disk utility doesn't see it also, but with other usb stick's everything is ok, so it's not the Ubuntu drivers."

Any other solution?